# Create timer and start it and get its value at anytime c#

Tags: c#, timer

I want to create a timer and start it and gets its value at any time in C# and I want to know what it is, depending on, for example, is it by seconds or milliseconds or so forth.

Comment: It might be worth noting that all solutions in .Net (inlcuding the stopwatch solution mentioned) are going to be dependant on the System namespace in way or another as that's the standard way for the framework to determine how much time has passed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you looking for the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class?

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// ...

var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// ...
var milliseconds = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Comment: ah, i always thought you had to Stop() first before reading EllapsedMilliseconds.  learn something new every day ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at Stopwatch class?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

This is another link with some good examples:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = Environment.TickCount;
// loop for 2 seconds
while(Environment.TickCount-start <2000)
{
    Console.Write(".");
}
Console.WriteLine("done");
```

Comment: is Environment.TickCount; need specific using classes ?

Comment: @salamonti: It's in the System namespace ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx)). You need to have `using System;` (or explicitly prefix it with `System.` each time). Chances are you're already `using System`, though.